Script Broken Overnight
I have a script that was supposed to update somewhat frequently- a couple times a day. It collects data from other sheets and compiles them into a master sheet. All of a sudden I started getting error reports in my email. I have not logged into the drive or edited the script at all, but I suddenly started getting this error:
"We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND."
I tried running the script, same error. The sheet has 4 scripts, none will run. I then tried to edit the script, but it would not let me save it. I tried to create a test script to check permissions, but it would not let me create a new script. No permissions around this page have been changed, I have absolutely no clue what could have caused this. I did try clearing cookies, changing browsers, incognito mode etc. No avail. I tried adding logging, but I can't add logging, and it's not even getting far enough to encounter an error to log.
Any help would be great.
Edit
I was looking through old error logs and found the following:
6/28:
Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id
It then ran fine for a couple weeks, before generating this error on 7/14:
Exceeded maximum execution time
It then ran fine until same error. Ran fine a couple more days until it turned into "server error" and "Not_Found" error. Since "Not_Found" error started on the 24th, it's been constant and I can't edit, fix, or test the script.
edit2
I also cannot Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor. I don't really understand, but it's like I'm locked out of my own script. I tried my colleagues computer, same issues. Makes no sense to me.
edit3
I was able to duplicate the container sheet and the issues were still at play. I duplicated the scripts and it was still at play. I was able to open the original scripts, copy their contents into a blank sheet, save those scripts, and then attach those to the duplicated container sheet, and now it works. However, I am very concerned about what happened to create this situation and how to address it in the future. Obviously something happened while I was not using my computer that broke everything.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question needs more focus. Please bear i mind that you can ask a another question about the second error messsage.

I don't understand what you're saying. I have no idea what happened. Open to suggestions for debugging, but I don't know what to do if I can't edit any of the scripts or run tests on what's not working.

Do any answers posted in the following question help? We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND

@RolandMiller Please bear in mind that questions on this site should be about "problems that are unique to programming", this is not a service or support desk. Please try to reproduce the problem and add enough details to allow other to reproduce it. If it can't be reproduced, then it's off-topic on this site. Also, questions should be specific, and should not include details that are no relevant to the specific problem. If the first error is no longer happening, please delete the question. Regarding the second error message, please post a new question incluidng a [mcve].
